# What is a 'CSS User'?

Tags: case, user

I'm creating a rule on a case comment. In the rule criteria, I can select fields from the 'Case Comment', the 'Case', the 'Current User' and the 'CSS User'. The fields from CSS User are a very small subset of the user fields (only: Active, Contact, Created By, created Date, Email, First Name, LanguageLocaleKey, Last Login, Last Modified By, Last Name, LocaleSidKey, Super User, TimeZoneSidKey, Username).

What is a CSS user? What's the difference with 'Current User'?

Comment: Can you help us with an image/screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Customer Self-Service ("CSS") user is used by the classic Self-Service Portal. It represents the customer who has logged in and is doing something with the case (e.g. logging the case, adding a case comment, closing the case, etc).

You can see the list of users under Setup > Customize > Self-Service > Self-Service Portal > Users. Newer organizations that have never used the SSP can only use the Customer Portal instead.

These fields are necessary because they are not "real" users (e.g. they do not have a 005X12 ID, but instead have a 035X12 ID).

Comment: Right, that old thing is indeed still in our org, thanks, I would never have thought of it as 'CSS'!

Answer (score -4):

CSS is a [Style-Sheet coding language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). **C**ustom **S**tyle **S**heets can be used [within Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_style_css_create_sheet.htm&language=en).

Comment: **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets

Comment: But i think the question is less about what CSS is and what a CSS user is in relation to Salesforce